# QML button toggling

Tags: qml

I want to have a button in QML that has 3 states: off, pressed, and on. right now I have the following for code, but it does not work. right now i have a toggle function that sets the new state based on the previous state, but if the previous state is "pressed" then how can I detect the state before it is pressed to toggle the button?

the following is not the whole class, just the relevant function and Mouse Area

```
    Rectangle {
        id: button1
        function toggle(){
            var tempstate = button1.state
            if (tempstate=="on") {tempstate = "off"; } else { tempstate ="on"}
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: parent.state = "pressed"
            onReleased: parent.toggle()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this using ternary conditional statements. instead of using 3 states, I use 2 states, where each state has a conditional based on the `MouseArea.pressed` property.

If this is somehow hackish or improper for QML, please correct me with a more idiomatic solution.

the color property of the Rectangle can be replaced with the source in an image item, or other properties to create other "3 state" clickable items.

[Here is the link to QML's documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html) where i realized this could be done.

Example code:

```
Rectangle {
    id: button1
    state: "off"
    color: "red"
    MouseArea {
        id: button1area
        anchors.fill: parent
        onReleased: parent.state == "on" ? parent.state = "off" : parent.state = "on"
    }
    states: [
        State {
            name: "off"
            PropertyChanges { target: button1; color: button1area.pressed ? "red" : "blue" }
        },
        State {
            name: "on"
            PropertyChanges { target: button1; color: button1area.pressed ? "green" : "blue" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Button? It can be checked so it's like on/off state and it has property 'pressed' indicating if button is currently pressed.

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
Button {
    checkable: true
    text: pressed ? "pressed" : (checked ? "on" : "off")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Rectangle {
   id: button1

   function toggle(){
       var tempstate = button1.state;  //write var if is local variable
       if (tempstate=="on") {state = "off"; } else { state = "on"}
   }

   MouseArea {
   anchors.fill: parent
   onPressed: parent.state = "pressed"
   onReleased: parent.toggle()
}
```

"tempstate" is holding the name of the state which is string. Its not having object reference.
You can directly access the state property in the function.

Comment: This is what I've come to since posting. However, this does not work because at the time of calling `toggle()` the state has already changed to `pressed` and the previous on/off state is lost. Closer, but still not working.